# probability of who will be selected

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

"In an office there are 3 secretaries, 4 accountants, and 2 receptionists. If a committee of 3 is to be formed, find the probability that one of each will be selected?

Attempted Solution:

First attempt: (3/9)*(4/9)*(2/9) = 8/243

Second attempt: (3/9)*(4/8)*(2/7) = 1/21

Don't if either of these are correct or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated to point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to say there are $\binom{9}{3}$ equally likely ways to choose $3$ people from the $9$. And there are $\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}$ ways to choose one of each kind. For the secretary can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways. For each such choice, the accompanying accountant can be chosen in $\binom{4}{1}$ ways. And once this has been done, the receptionist can be chosen in $\binom{2}{1}$ ways.

For the probability, divide "favourables" by "total." We get
$$\frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}.$$

**Another way:** Imagine choosing the people one at a time. We find the probability of choosing a secretary, **then** an accountant, **then** a receptionist.

The probability the first person chosen was an S is $\frac{3}{9}$. **Given** this happened, the probability the next chosen person was an A is $\frac{4}{8}$. and given this happened, the probability the next person chosen was an S is $\frac{2}{7}$, for a probability of $\frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{7}$.

But there are several other ways we could end up with one of each, for example A then S then R. If you calculate, this ends up having the probability $\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{7}$. This is the **same number** as the one previously obtained.

There are in total $3!=6$ ways we can end up with one of each. so the required probability is 
$$6\cdot \frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{7}.$$
The first way is (after you get used to it) easier.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that I still don't understand how to use Hypergeometric Distribution Probability. I have been struggling with this ever since grade 11 and no matter how much help I get or no matter what I try, I don't seem to get the hang of it. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to actually get the hang of these?

Comment: I would suggest going through the *reasoning* each time. So I suggest remembering an *idea*, not a formula. I have given an alternate (but less attractive) way of making the calculation.

Comment: Note that the calculation that gave you $\frac{1}{21}$ is closely related to the second solution that I gave. Except that your $\frac{1}{21}$ gives the probability of getting a secretary, an accountant, and a receptionist **in that order**. But there are $5$ other orders possible, each of which also turns out to have probability $\frac{1}{21}$. So we must multiply your $\frac{1}{21}$ by $6$. It is, however, cleanest and safest to do the first type of analysis.